# Show Navigation to next Node

Tags: views, 8

I need to create a views block, that is shown on a node page that outputs a link to the next node that comes in the sort logic (defined in a view).

The module flippy does not work as it does not respect filters.

I am pretty sure that this can be achieved in views only.

How would I set up a view?

Comment: Use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next ,configure it for specific node in module configuration ,In  manage display of node type you will get 2 option prev and next,these links will display in Content region of node